# Xcode 7 crashes when selected main storyboard

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I'm using Xcode 7 beta and I create a blank new project and go to the main storyboard and then I get the spinny beach ball of death and it crashes? wtf is going on

Comment: Since it is a beta, it's understandable it can be unreliable. I'd suggest waiting for beta 5.

Comment: Adding to @BojanDimovski's comment, if you're just starting out, I would seek to minimize variables. I would go with a stable release for learning, as you're less prone to bump into flakiness with the app and solutions to things you'll encounter are more prevalent.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I edited the project.pbxproj on an app to fix an error but nothing happened, I changed it back and still nothing...The bad thing is that it effected all my macs and I cannot program anymore since it is not compiling the storyboard....also downgrading did not help at all. Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: it crashes in xcode 6 too, so i cant develop at all.  and im not learning im working on a project.

Comment: I had to reinstall osx and now it works :/